# Mysql now () + INTERVAL 1 DAY returns 0000-00-00 00:00:00 on live server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I was working on a project. I just uploaded it to my live server. When users post a job, I'm using the mysql now() + INTERVAL with the job delivery time to set an expiration so that I can then select expired jobs without selecting all of the jobs. this works fine in my local development environment but on live it inserts 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in db.

Any suggestions?

```
$job['delivery_time'] = 8; // can have a number from 1 to 29

$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs(job_id, posted_by, title, category_id, description, required_freelancers, budget, delivery_time, job_expiration, date_posted, updated_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now() + INTERVAL " . $job['delivery_time'] . " DAY, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);

$current_time = date('U');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssisisiii', $job['id'], $user_id, $job['title'], $job['category'], $job['description'], $job['required_freelancers'], $job['budget'], $job['delivery_time'], $current_time, $current_time);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: Have you checked what the string `$sql` is on the live server? That could narrow down where it is going wrong.

Comment: What is in `$job['delivery_time']`?

Comment: @Nick `$job['delivery_time']` can have a number from 1 to 29.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I have also ran the query inside phpmyadmin still the same result

Comment: @LachiWeb What is the value of `now()` on the server?